# Как выбрать первую строку, удовлетворяющую условию?

Tags: python, pandas, запрос, select

Вот набор данных:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({"par1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                     "par2": [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                     "par3": [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
                     })

test
Out[45]: 
   par1  par2  par3
0     1    11    21
1     2    12    22
2     3    13    23
3     4    14    24
4     5    15    25
```

Как получить первую строку, удовлетворяющую набору условий?

Конкретно у меня есть набор  чисел p1, p2, p3. Как выбрать первую строку, для которой верно условие par1>p1 & par2>p2 & par3>p3?  Например найти коробку, в которую влезет объект с размерами p1, p2, p3.

Вот мое решение:

```
test[(test["par1"]>2) & (test["par2"]>13) &  (test["par3"]>1)].iloc[0, :]

Out[43]: 
par1     4
par2    14
par3    24
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

Есть подозрение, что в Pandas есть более эффективное решение . Это как выход из цикла по условию с помощью break. Выбор ВСЕХ записей, удовлетворяющих условию явно избыточен.

Comment: Судя по всему, чистого пандасовоского решения нет.

Comment: Я бы попробовал ещё Dask как вариант, возможно, он лишние операции и отрежет

Comment: @CrazyElf, я еще не встречал случая/примера, когда операция в Dask отработала бы быстрее аналогичной операции в Pandas. Стоимость накладных расходов на распараллеливание в Dask достаточно высокая. PS правда последний раз я баловался с Dask года два назад - может они в корне изменили движок за это время... :-D

Comment: @MaxU Я всё же потестил ради интереса. Похоже, Dask только на каких-то аггрегатных функциях может выехать или ещё каких-то таких случаях, когда весь датафрейм в память не помещается, а делать что-то хочется. Numba вот возрулила, а Dask показал даже чуть худший результат, чем Pandas :/

Comment: @CrazyElf, когда я сравнивал производительность Pandas и Dask, Dask оказался в 10 раз медленнее Pandas. Поэтому я для себя тогда сделал вывод - если хватает памяти, использовать Pandas, а если не хватает тогда Dask или ещё лучше Apache Spark

Comment: @MaxU Есть ещё vaex по типу даска, но сходу он в колабе не завёлся, а так вроде обещали, что он лучше, но я так ни разу толком и не попробовал

Comment: @CrazyElf, видел упоминания о нем здесь на SO, но самому поиграться с ним ещё не доводилось)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120669/discussion-between-maxu-and-crazyelf).

Comment: @CrazyElf, [вот интересное сравнение](https://www.datarevenue.com/en-blog/pandas-vs-dask-vs-vaex-vs-modin-vs-rapids-vs-ray) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"более эффективное" решение не будет векторизированным, т.к. придётся использовать цикл. Поэтому может оказаться медленнее чем "менее эффективное". ;)

В качестве альтернативы можно воспользоваться Numba:

```
from numba import prange, njit, jit, i8

@njit('i8(i8[:, :], i8, i8, i8)')
def fun(arr, p1, p2, p3):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i, 0] > p1 and arr[i, 1] > p2 and arr[i, 2] > p3:
            return i
    return -1
```

тесты:

```
In [59]: idx = fun(test.to_numpy(), p1, p2, p3)

In [60]: res = test.iloc[idx] if idx >= 0 else None

In [61]: res
Out[61]:
par1     4
par2    14
par3    24
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

Для массивов данных более 1.000.000 записей советую воспользоваться GPU [(`numba + cuda`)](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.13/CUDAJit.html) или [`cupy`](https://cupy.dev/).

PS сравнение скорости работы на больших массивах оставлю вам)

Comment: а почему вы импортировали `prange`, но не использовали его?

Comment: @Danis, потому что изначально планировал его использовать

Answer (score 3):

### Сравнение производительности для фрейма: `(5000, 3)`

```
df = pd.concat([test] * 10**3, ignore_index=True)

df.shape
>>> (5000, 3)
```

#### Pandas

```
%timeit df[(df["par1"]>2) & (df["par2"]>13) &  (df["par3"]>1)].iloc[0]
>>> 846 µs ± 6.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.query("par1 > 2 and par2 > 13 and par3 > 1").iloc[0]
>>> 1.87 ms ± 11.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

#### [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/5minguide.html)

```
%%timeit
idx = fun(df.to_numpy(), 2, 13, 1)
res = df.iloc[idx] if idx >= 0 else None
>>> 74.9 µs ± 577 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%%timeit
idx = fun(df.to_numpy(), 2, 13, 1000)
res = df.iloc[idx] if idx >= 0 else None
>>> 8.34 µs ± 63.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

#### [Modin[ray]](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
%timeit df[(df["par1"]>2) & (df["par2"]>13) &  (df["par3"]>1)].iloc[0]
>>> 11.9 s ± 267 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.query("par1 > 2 and par2 > 13 and par3 > 1").iloc[0]
>>> 2.3 s ± 645 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Вывод

- Pandas: 1 (baseline)
- Numba: 0.0885 (в 11 раз быстрее Pandas)
- Modin[ray]: 2.7187 (в 2.7187 медленнее Pandas)

PS я ожидал от разрекламированного `modin[ray]` большего.