# Как посчитать количество элементов до определенного значения?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Дан df:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 1},

                  {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 4, 'd': 1},])
```

В каждом `id` будет только одна строка, где `b == 1` и ниже 5 строк с `b == 2`
Нужно, сгруппировав по id, среди строк, где `b == 2`, посчитать количество строк, где `d == 0` и записать в колонку `k`, но сделать это следующим образом:

1. берем первую встретившуюся строку с `b == 2`, если у нее `d == 0`, то `k` = 1
2. далее вторую строку с `b == 2`, если у нее `d == 0`, то `k` уже будет = 2
3. и так все 5 строк с `b == 2` пока не попадется `d == 1`
4. то есть если в первой же строке с `b == 2` `d == 1`, то `k` = 0 и следующие строки с `b == 2` в этом `id` мы уже не рассматриваем.

В итоге должно получится вот так:

```
        pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'k': 3},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0, 'k': 3},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0, 'k': 3},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0, 'k': 3},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1, 'k': 3},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1, 'k': 3},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 1, 'k': 3},
    
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'k': 1},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0, 'k': 1},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1, 'k': 1},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0, 'k': 1},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1, 'k': 1},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1, 'k': 1},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 4, 'd': 1, 'k': 1}])
```

Судя по ответу от @strawdog на мой предыдущий похожий вопрос [Pandas посчитать количество элементов равное заданному значению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1256344/362663), мы также должны использовать:

```
a["k"] = a.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: (x["b"]==2)&(x["d"] == 0)).groupby("id").transform(sum).to_list()
```

Но там необходимо было посчитать количество в целом, а здесь нужно посчитать количество до первого встретившегося `d == 1`, как можно добавить такое условие, не могу понять

P.S. Возможно, стоит просто сгруппировать по id и b == 2:

```
DD = a.query("b == 2").groupby('id')
AA = 0
```

Далее циклом перебирать каждую строку в каждом id, если d == 0, то обновить счетчик AA += 1, если d != 0, то break.

Но мягко говоря, такое решение кажется неадекватным, и что-то мне подсказывает, что можно решить эту ситуацию более удобными и быстрыми встроенными в Pandas методами.

P.S. @strawdog, если меняю входящий df на:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 1},

                  {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 4, 'd': 1}])
```

то на выходе получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в столбце `k` должны быть 1 и 0 для 1 и 2 id соответственно:

---

P.S. Пробую делать вот таким корявым способом:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 0},

                  {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 4, 'd': 0},])

DD = a.query("b == 2").groupby('id')
for i in DD['d']:
    K = 0
    for index, j in enumerate(i):
        if index == 1:
    
            for m in j:
                if m == 0:
                    K += 1
                else:
                    break

    print(K)

  >>> 5
  >>> 1
```

То считается правильно вроде как, остается только эти цифры для каждого id добавить в колонку `k`. Но данный способ мне не нравится, он наверняка относительно затратный + я не до конца понимаю зачем мне приходится столько циклов перебирать)) С Pandas у меня проблемы, поэтому заранее сорри.

Comment: У вас df всегда состоит из блоков по семь строк или вы только гарантируете, что в нем для каждого id ровно пять строк с df['b'] == 2?

Comment: df ,будет не по 7 строк, но строк с df['b'] == 2 в каждом id всегда будет ровно 5

Comment: df['d'] всегда {0, 1} или может быть {0, !=0}?

Comment: А как должны выглядеть значения “k” для группы значений “b” и “d”: [(1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0), (2, 0), (2, 0)] ?

Comment: да, df['d'] всегда {0, 1}

Comment: @MaxU k = 1, в таком случае

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если я правильно понял логику алгоритма:

```
a["k"] = (a["id"]
          .map(a.assign(x=a["d"].eq(0).astype(int))
                .query("b==2")
                .groupby("id")
                ["x"]
                .apply(lambda x: x.cumprod().cumsum().max())))
```

результат:

```
In [171]: a
Out[171]:
    id  b  d  k
0    1  1  1  3
1    1  2  0  3
2    1  2  0  3
3    1  2  0  3
4    1  2  1  3
5    1  2  1  3
6    1  4  1  3
7    2  1  1  1
8    2  2  0  1
9    2  2  1  1
10   2  2  0  1
11   2  2  1  1
12   2  2  1  1
13   2  4  1  1
```

---

пошагово:

сначала создаем вспомогательный виртуальный столбец `x` со значением `1` в тех строках, где `d == 0` и `0` во всех остальных строках и фильтруем строки оставляя только те, где `b == 2`:

```
In [173]: a.assign(x=a["d"].eq(0).astype(int)).query("b==2")
Out[173]:
    id  b  d  k  x
1    1  2  0  3  1
2    1  2  0  3  1
3    1  2  0  3  1
4    1  2  1  3  0
5    1  2  1  3  0
8    2  2  0  1  1
9    2  2  1  1  0
10   2  2  0  1  1
11   2  2  1  1  0
12   2  2  1  1  0
```

теперь группируем записи по `id` и считаем кумулятивное произведение по столбцу `x` в каждой группе - это обнулит все значения в группе, начиная с первой встретившийся строки  у которой `d != 0`:

```
In [174]: a.assign(x=a["d"].eq(0).astype(int)).query("b==2").groupby("id")["x"].apply(lambda x: x.cumprod())
Out[174]:
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     0
5     0
8     1
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

далее считаем кумулятивную сумму значения, получившегося на предыдущем шаге для каждой группы:

```
In [175]: a.assign(x=a["d"].eq(0).astype(int)).query("b==2").groupby("id")["x"].apply(lambda x: x.cumprod().cumsum())
Out[175]:
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     3
5     3
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

и берем максимальное значение для каждой группы:

```
In [176]: a.assign(x=a["d"].eq(0).astype(int)).query("b==2").groupby("id")["x"].apply(lambda x: x.cumprod().cumsum().max())
Out[176]:
id
1    3
2    1
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

в итоге используем получившийся ряд, подставляя вместо `id` соответствующее значение из этого ряда и присваивая результат новому столбцу (см. решение целиком выше).

Comment: Да, оно) Все вроде как работает правильно. Спасибо большое! Я говорю вы гений, такую задачу одной строкой решить... Буду детальнее разбираться с .eq() .cumsum() .cumprob(), я про них пока ничего не знаю даже. Скажите, а последний способ мой в вопросе, вообще имеет место быть?) Понятно, что через циклы это решение очень затратное, но чисто в теории, если объем небольшой, можно было так сделать и потом присвоить каждому id полученное число? Или это вообще бред?

Comment: @ChikChirik, иногда решения с циклами гораздо быстрее по сравнению с Pandas-решениями если обернуть функцию `JIT` декоратором из модуля `Numba` - [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1253735/211923). В общем почти всегда нужно сравнивать производительность разных подходов на больших (правдоподобных) датасетах.

Answer (score 4):

Довольно сложное условие для векторизованной обработки фрейма. Я думаю, вам нужно как-то по-другому готовить данные перед помещением их в таблицу. Пока же я ничего более изящного, чем код ниже, придумать не смог:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 0},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 4, 'd': 1},])

a["k"] =  a[((a["b"]==1)&(a["d"]==1))|((a["b"]==2)&(a["d"]==1))]["b"].astype("bool")
a["k"] = a["k"].fillna(0).cumsum()

res = pd.DataFrame()
for i, g in a.groupby("k"):
    t = g.copy()
    zeros = t["d"].to_list().count(0)
    t["k"] = t["d"].to_list().count(0)    
    res = pd.concat([res, t])
    
res["k"] = res["k"].replace(0, np.nan).fillna(method="ffill").astype("int")
```

res:

```
    id  b  d  k
0    1  1  1  3
1    1  2  0  3
2    1  2  0  3
3    1  2  0  3
4    1  2  1  3
5    1  2  1  3
6    1  4  1  3
7    2  1  1  1
8    2  2  0  1
9    2  2  1  1
10   2  2  0  1
11   2  2  1  1
12   2  2  1  1
13   2  4  1  1
```

Comment: что-то не так немного, если меняю входящий df, то на выходе получаю не то,дополнил вопрос вашим ответом, сюда иначе не помещается.

Comment: Вероятно, я не совсем понимаю задачу, В соответствии с моим прочтением, решение для вашего другого датафрейма получается верным. Еще раз подчеркну, набор условия довольно нетривиален.

Comment: Попробовал еще разные варианты, одна из ошибок в том, что учитываются не только b == 2, то есть если у всех строк с `id == 1` сделать `['d'] = 0`, то в k будет 7, а у нас возможны только значения от 0 до 5, так как мы берем только `b == 2` (таких значений у каждого id всегда ровно 5), и еще если мы у самой первой строки с b == 2, ставим в ['d'] значение 1, то код его пропускает и уже считает со следующей строки, но в k в таком случае должен записаться 0.

Comment: не знаете как исправить?

Comment: добавил в самый низ вопроса, свое корявое решение, считает вроде верно, но проблема в том, чтобы добавить эти цифры теперь к каждому id, можете посмотреть, пожалуйста?