# Как работает функция: lambda x: i if i in x else x?

Tags: python, pandas

Как это работает:

```
for i in list:
    data['object_name'] = data['object_name'].apply(lambda x: i if i in x else x)
```

Comment: Здесь несколько разных действий. Какой конкретно фрагмент непонятен.

Comment: .apply(lambda x: i if i in x else x)

Comment: это решение к тому же и не самое удачное - скорее всего это можно сделать без цикла. Но чтобы сказать наверняка нужен небольшой воспроизводимый пример данных и результат, который вы хотите получить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lambda x: i if i in x else x
```

это безымянный эквивалент следующей функции:

```
def fun(x):
    if i in x:
        return i
    else:
        return x
```

эта функция применяется ко всем элементам столбца `data['object_name']`

Comment: добавил в самый низ вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1256558/362663, свое корявое решение, считает вроде верно, но проблема в том, чтобы добавить эти цифры теперь к каждому id, можете посмотреть, пожалуйста?